# Can I find a function of $y$ that satisfies the relation $\dfrac{df(y)}{dx} = y^2(3y'+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have an unknown function $y=y(x)$  , is it possible to find a function $f(y)$ such that:
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}= y^2\left(3\dfrac{dy}{dx}+1 \right)$$?

**EDIT:** of course if there is no $1$ in the RHS, the solution will be $f(y) = y^3$

I appreciate any help

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've done derivatives, been here's my attempt.

We're just trying to solve $\frac{d}{dx}[f(y)] = y^{2}(3\frac{dy}{dx} + 1) = 3y^{2}\frac{dy}{dx} + y^{2}$. Thus, integrate both sides by $x$ to find $f(y)$:

$$
\int 3y^{2}\frac{dy}{dx} + y^{2} dx = \int 3y^{2}\frac{dy}{dx} dx + \int y^{2} dx.
$$

The first integral is, of course, $y^{3}$ as you mentioned. The second integral can only be determined once $y(x)$ has been defined. Hence, we can write

$$
f(y) = y^{3} + \int y^{2} dx.
$$

Comment: $y(x)$ is unknown

Comment: Hence why I wrote "The second integral can only be determined once $y(x)$ has been defined". You cannot evaluate the integral of a general function of that form - at least, not that I know of.

Comment: this is why I asked this question, I guess the answer will be heuristic